# Wi-Fi router with USB NAS

Tags: wireless-router, nas, bridge

I want a Wi-Fi router with USB NAS (The idea is that I can connect my USB drives and then have them in my LAN).

It seems it is not so straightforward.
When there is a USB in the router, it is not clear it can really be used as a NAS.
And also it seems I can't use an USB hub with it.

Are there any WI-Fi routers that does the job of USB NAS quite well?

Should I look for another kind of device, like a WI-FI USB NAS?

Does USB Hubs generally only work well with real computers?

The idea is to have a core wired high-speed network, where other devices can connect seamlessly with Wi-FI.

Comment: you should refine you requirements. USB NAS performance is terrible. It's really marketing feature for routers.

Comment: Is it just a bit slow (slower than a direct connection when the network is not a limit), or is it unstable?

Comment: Is it much slower than a direct USB connection?

Comment: On direct connection you can get 25-30 MBps write speed and 30-42 MBps read speed. Best in category router give you 66%-50% read speed and 60% write speed. But I've seen routers with 1MBps read/write transfer rate.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some interesting information in this review:
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3132_7-57494092-98/top-five-wi-fi-routers-with-built-in-network-storage/

Top performing router in NAS category performs 20MBps for reading and 19MBps for writing with attached USB hard drive over Gigabit Ethernet. USB limits all transfer ~30MBps. Gigabit Ethernet limits transfer ~110MBps.

Comment: Had a short look.  They are not all with USB NAS, and the first one I could see had only one USB, with no possibility for HUB.